# Как правильно использовать data-image в stylus?

Tags: css, gulp, stylus

при попытке задать фон для элемента на основе данных из указанного источника (через конструкцию `url()` ), пакет `gulp-stylus` при компиляции файла выдает ошибку:

> expected ")", got ";"

вот так не работает:

```
.myEl 
   background url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgo.....)
```

а вот так работает

```
.myEl 
   background yellow
```

почему первый пример не рабочий?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте кавычки

```
.myEl 
   background url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgo.....")
```

http://codepen.io/Zoxon/pen/vLKXXy